# MYSQL multiple OR's and AND's

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok, so I have built this query with my PHP script:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sale_properties 
WHERE advert_heading LIKE '%harnham%' 
   OR main_advert LIKE '%harnham%' 
   OR advert2 LIKE '%harnham%' 
   OR advert3 LIKE '%harnham%' 
   OR street LIKE '%harnham%' 
   OR district LIKE '%harnham%' 
   OR town LIKE '%harnham%' 
   OR county LIKE '%harnham%' 
   OR area LIKE '%harnham%' 
   OR postcode LIKE '%harnham%' 
   AND numeric_price >= 150000.00 
   AND numeric_price <= 152000.00
```

Now, this does give me some results, however, I want to basically search the database for the keyword and within the price range. The query above does give me the keyword but seems to ignore most of the price range.

Does this look correct? or could it be built better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try with parentheses...

```
SELECT * FROM sale_properties WHERE
 (
    advert_heading LIKE '%harnham%' OR
    main_advert LIKE '%harnham%' OR
    advert2 LIKE '%harnham%' OR
    advert3 LIKE '%harnham%' OR
    street LIKE '%harnham%' OR
    district LIKE '%harnham%' OR
    town LIKE '%harnham%' OR
    county LIKE '%harnham%' OR
    area LIKE '%harnham%' OR
    postcode LIKE '%harnham%'
) AND (
    numeric_price >= 150000.00 AND
    numeric_price <= 152000.00
)
```

Comment: Great, works :) Thanks for the help, i will accept this answer when it lets me :)

Comment: +1 The second set of parentheses is not strictly required.

Comment: @MarkBannister yes you are right, but it keeps sql well formatted, that's why i use it...

Answer (score 2):

While there are some rules how an or-and expression is evaluated (operator precedence tables and things like that), those are hard to get right, and very hard to debug.

It's best if, as a rule of thumb you try never to mix `and`s and `or`s on the same level of an expression.

You should rewrite the query as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sale_properties 
WHERE 
     (advert_heading LIKE '%harnham%' 
      OR main_advert LIKE '%harnham%' 
      OR advert2 LIKE '%harnham%' 
      OR advert3 LIKE '%harnham%' 
      OR street LIKE '%harnham%' 
      OR district LIKE '%harnham%' 
      OR town LIKE '%harnham%' 
      OR county LIKE '%harnham%' 
      OR area LIKE '%harnham%' 
     OR postcode LIKE '%harnham%')
   AND 
     (numeric_price >= 150000.00 
      AND numeric_price <= 152000.00)
```

So that it basically becomes a single `and` between two expressions. The first expression (the part with the `like`s ) is true only if any of its part are true, and the second part (the numeric_price check) is true only if both its parts are true. The whole thing is true only if both sub-expressions are true.

Comment: The latter pair of parentheses around the ANDs is redundant

Comment: The point of those parenthesis is to separate the conditions into logical parts, that are easy for a human to parse - code is written for other humans to read after all. Like this we have an `and` between two independent conditions, so it's easier to grok what the code does.

Answer (score 1):

This is like mathematical operation, you must use parentheses.

Comment: Where would you put the parentheses?

Comment: Do you want programming, and does not know the rules of performing mathematical operations?

Comment: As usual, AND always binds stronger than OR... lookup any programming language's operator precedence...